# I can't input the right value for string in a list box

Tags: c#, string, listbox, radio-button

Hi I am currently working on a project in my algorithm class. It is a database which searches a list of names for some other names that contains the same letters etc. Whenever a certain radio button becomes checked, the program is supposed to add some names. The program does it well, but instead of putting the names like shown lower, it puts it in one line.

It is supposed to look like this but instead it's in one line.

WILLIAM

THOMAS

FELIX

LIAM

Here's the text lines (the most important ones)

```
    {
        lstPrénoms.Items.Clear();
        lstPrénoms.Items.Add("WILLIAM\r\nTHOMAS\r\nFELIX\r\nLIAM\r\n");
    }
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong with my text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Split to split up your string to multiple lines like this:

```
string s = "WILLIAM\r\nTHOMAS\r\nFELIX\r\nLIAM\r\n";
foreach (string st in s.Split('\r', '\n'))
  listBox1.Items.Add(st);
```

Comment: No need for regex, this can be done with `string.Split` just as well.

Comment: yeah you are right! it did not come to my mind in the first place. updated answer

Comment: when i do it, it just puts

WILLIAMTHOMASFELIXLIAM

WILLIAMTHOMASFELIXLIAM

WILLIAMTHOMASFELIXWILLIAM